# Rails 3 Model Name Convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, convention

Can anyone explain me about a model name convention in Rails 3?

For example:
I have a table named "materialtitles" in my database.
What name does a model file, a model class have to satisfy convention of names in Rails???

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you using a legacy db schema? better choice would be `material_titles`. if it is a legacy schema, you could name your model `MaterialTitle` and use `set_table_name "materialtitles"` (at the top of your model class declaration) to use a non-conventional table name. with a legacy schema you often have to break a convention, it's your choice if you'd rather break the model name <-> table name convention, or the camelcase model name convention

Comment: Thanks for answer. Bu what does "legacy db schema" mean?

Comment: are you writing a rails app for an existing database and therefore can't change table names, or can you choose the structure and table names etc freely?

Comment: I'm owner for this database, therefore I can change anything I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename would be `materialtitle.rb` and would reside in app/models.

The class name of your model would be would be `Materialtitle`.